# problem in if & else?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why don't work `if(length_pa >= 16){ ...` after select value "2" in select box and don't work `if(length_pa == 0){...` after select value "all" in select box???
[with change length(number) in `"var length_pa" $('#pagination a')` don't work "show" and "hide" for `#prev_pag, #next_pag`.]

**EXAMPLE:** [See This](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show)

```
var length_pa = $('.pagination a').size();
    if(length_pa >= 16){
        $('.prev_pag, .next_pag').show();
    }else{
        $('.prev_pag, .next_pag').hide();
        $('.pagination').css('float','none')
    }
    if(length_pa == 0){
        alert('0000000000')
        $('.hesar_number').css('display','none');
    }
```

what do i do?

**Explanation:** 
If that value `2` be select, `.prev_pag, .next_pag` must show
If that value 'all' be select, `.hesar_number` must hide(`'display','none'`)
But these does not happen... why!?

Comment: You really have to explain your problem better. I don't even know what you mean with *don't work*. How can an `if` statement not work?

Comment: @Felix - did you see it true(worked)?

Comment: Please see **Explanation** in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted only appears to be in the `$(document).ready` block, which means it's *only* executed when the page is first loaded. Did you mean to add it to the `$('#coun_page').change` event?

```
$('#coun_page').change(function() {
    var length_pa = $('.pagination a').size();

    if (length_pa >= 16) { 
        $('.prev_pag, .next_pag').show(); 
    } else { 
        $('.prev_pag, .next_pag').hide(); 
        $('.pagination').css('float','none');
    }

    if (length_pa == 0) { 
        alert('0000000000');
        $('.hesar_number').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see **Explanation** in my first post.

Comment: @Sheikhasa: Your site still uses your original code and not the one suggest by Dan Tao.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you are missing semicolons.

```
var length_pa = $('.pagination a').size();
if(length_pa >= 16) {
    $('.prev_pag, .next_pag').show();
}
else {
    $('.prev_pag, .next_pag').hide()
    $('.pagination').css('float', 'none'); // Semicolon was missing
}
if(length_pa == 0) {
    alert('0000000000'); // Semicolon was missing
    $('.hesar_number').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: Setting semicolon's is good practice but omitting them does not result in an error (at least not in this case).

Comment: @tmcopeland - Right told you, but this did not solve the problem. There is it still

Comment: Please see **Explanation** in my first post.